# how to get drawing object before it's complete?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using drawing. DrawingManager and I want to restrict drawing a polyline with more then 2 points,so basically it will be just a line. I can do it after the polyline is complete with the `polylinecomplete` event.

But i want to catch the event when it's adding a point to the path so i can jut turn off the polyline drawing mode. I have thought to catch it with click event but as it turns out

> google.maps.Map events, such as click and mousemove are disabled while drawing on the map.

and i don't see any events like the one I need in documentation.

Is there a way to catch the event of adding a point to the polyline path or just click event?

Comment: Short answer: no. There is no other event available than polylinecomplete.

Comment: Why do you need the Drawing Library? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to restrict drawing a polyline with more then 2 points. So it stops the polyline drawing mode after there are 2 points, and just leaves a line.

Comment: Yes. I understood that. But what is the goal? Could you not just use a simple [polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline)?

Comment: The goal is to show the direction of a object(like it goes from here to here) and it need to be shown by a line like an arrow, and if after putting 2 point it continues to draw, like it does, it will be confusing for people how to use it. They might think that they need to draw more or something. And after that using those 2 points i'll check is object facing south or not.

Comment: Did you consider my suggestion to use a simple polyline instead?

Comment: You mean like not use the drawing manager polyline drawing mode and make my own ? That will draw simple lines ?

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean. Using a simple polyline, you could easily force it to stop drawing after 2 points.

Comment: yeah i think i can try that and can i just attach my polyline to that drawing manager button ? So it keeps that one bar just uses not build in but my polyline drawing? Or i need to make a button on the side ?

Comment: No, you would need to create your own *button* or link to activate the drawing or have it active by default.